# Why are my menu items not showing under the top level menu item?

Tags: routes

I'd like my other 3 menu items to sit under Manage Instagram in my Admin/Config menu but they are all being created as individual top level menu items.

```
  function instagram_menu() {

  $items = array();

  // Top Level Menu Item
  $items['admin/config/instagram'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage Instagram',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  // Secondary Level Menu Item
  $items['admin/config/instagram/pull-images'] = array(
    'title' => 'Pull Instagram Images',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('instagram_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  // Secondary Level Menu Item
  $items['admin/config/instagram/client_id'] = array(
    'title' => 'Set Instagram Client ID',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('instagram_client_id_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  // Secondary Level Menu Item
  $items['admin/config/instagram/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete Instagram Data',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('instagram_delete_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Drupal menu item types](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu_item_types/7) you need to designate which item is the parent and designate the children as such. So in your case, I believe setting your 3 links as MENU_LOCAL_ACTION should resolve the issue. You might have to designate the top level menu item as MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK to make it work depending on your settings.